# Eclipse IDE for JDK on a server

Tags: java, eclipse

Is it possible that I can use Eclipse as an IDE on my laptop and the JDK is on a server (and not on the same laptop as the IDE)?

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use Eclipse for Java development without a JDK installed.

Do you really need to use Eclipse without a JDK, or are you actually trying to do [remote debugging](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cremdbug.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse requires a Java installation on your laptop to work locally.  There is no easy way to publish compiled classes to a remote server and invoke a remote JVM for running or debugging, but you can manually start the remote JDK in debug mode and let your Eclipse debugger connect to that.

Note, that if the server runs Linux or a UNIX-dialect, then you can *run* Eclipse on the server, and let it provide its GUI on your local machine across the network if you have an X11 server installed (OS X builtin, Windows has several) and compress the network traffic.

Comment: I think this is all irrelevant to the actual question, but why would it be hard to publish classes to a remote server and invoke a remote JVM? Ant can scp, ssh, and send arbitrary commands.

Comment: @Isaac, needing to script it with ant instead of having Eclipse GUI support moves it out of the "easy" domain.   The OP may not be as well acquainted with ant as you.

Comment: ørn Then we have very different definitions of "easy" obviously. Is installing an Eclipse plugin too hard? http://www.eclipse.org/tm/ http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ Both of those have features for interacting with remote servers if Ant is too hard.