# Setting up Java + svn + Eclipse+ Tomcat , development environment with docker

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I just started to tryout docker to see if it helps setting up our development environment , which consists of

1. Jdk 1.6
2. Eclipse
3. RabbitVCS
4. Tomcat
5. MySQL server

Our Development desktops are mostly Ubuntu 16.04 . I would have eclipse, RabbitVCS installed on host and the rest in container .

If every thing goes well , developers should be able to download a Docker image . Running that image should give them JDK , Tomcat and MySQL server . Developers can then start using RabbitVCS to check out projects .

Is this feasible with Docker ?

Comment: Yes it is feasible

Comment: Can you help me with some details .   I already installed jdk and mysql .  opened port 3306 etc ... in a container .

Comment: You should probably try git instead of RabbitVCS

Comment: I recommend you consult [this official Docker guide](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/developer-tools/java-debugging/Eclipse-README.md) on using Eclipse to debug a live running container. Basically has the pattern you need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### tl;dr

It is **not feasible** to run eclipse in host OS and use JDK/JRE runs in a container because eclipse has a dependency on JRE. Similarly you cannot have tomcat in one container and JRE/JDK in another container because tomcat needs JRE to run.

### Explanation

> I would have eclipse, RabbitVCS installed on host and the rest in container....... Running that image should give them JDK , Tomcat and MySQL server

Are you trying to use JDK running on a docker container (and Eclipse IDE running on host os) for active development? If that is the case, **it not not feasible** (arguable, you can do remote debugging; but remember, debugging is very different than active development) . And it is not the intend of docker. While developing, your developers may need to have JDK installed in their host machine itself. In your case, only sensible thing to run from container is mysql as you don't have any active development there.

## Edit: To build a portable development environment

In docker-land, one possible solution is, have eclipse+jdk+tomcat in the same docker image and mount the X11 socket into the container so that you can expose eclipse GUI running in the container to your host OS

More read here: https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/

Or just ditch Docker and go to full-blown VM like [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), you might be able to find pre-built images with eclipse in it (not sure), or you can build one after installing all the required packages on a base image and share it amongst your developers.

Comment: It is possible to connect Eclipse with Tomcat by forwarding some ports for debugging purposes (eg. https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-debug-app-on-tomcat-running-inside-the-container/4216/4). There are many benefits of having java in a different container. For example you could have multiple containers with multiple 'isolated' JDK versions for testing your application. Also, it's much easier and faster to setup the entire suit on different development environments (windows/mac/linux) without too much hassle.

Comment: I think you didnot get it.. debugging is very different than active development. First of all, eclipse needs a JRE to run (wherever you are running the eclipse, not on any other container). Second, eclipse come with a compiler you don't necessarily have to have JDK installed (again, arguable). Have you tried yourself developing in the above-said set up? I suggest read more here https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722905/eclipse-ide-for-jdk-on-a-server (not so-authentic, but still)

Comment: @so-random-dude . Ok , I'm in the process of figuring out the best approach to Dockerise  our development environment . Currently I am trying out Adi's suggestion . Is this this best approach . I am trying to build a portable development environment . What is your suggestion .

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's feasible.

I would recommend to use different containers for each service (Mysql/Tomcat/JDK). You could use docker-compose to connect the containers together and automate a lot of tasks. There are plenty of images already on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/) that you can use.

Here's an simple example of how you can setup your own docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
    tomcat_service:
    #contains tomcat & jdk
        image: tomcat
        volumes:
            - /local/path:/path/in/docker
        links:
            - mysql_service
        depends_on:
            - mysql_service
        ports:
            - "80:80"
          # - other ports for debugging

    mysql_service:
        image: mysql
        volumes:
            #you should keep mysql data on the host, not in container
            - /local/path/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Each image used above will be downloaded automatically from dockerhub:
[tomcat](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/), [java](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/), [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/)

**EDIT:** jdk and tomcat would be better together in the same container

Comment: "EDIT: jdk and tomcat would be better together in the same container" -- how else you suggest tomcat will run?

Comment: @so-random-dude I suppose he meant to use the JDK of tomcat container, and don't have another container for JDK separately.

Comment: Any idea on how to configure eclipse to use tomcat server from docker container?